# Why is MSDN telling me to create a OAuth2.0 client when I just want a barebone test for my API?

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I have a REST API, written with express directly. Nowhere in it do I use session, and authentification is for now done using [JWT](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken).

However, I dislike having to handle, save and secure user's credentials, that is when I heard about Azure Active Directory.

Adding [passport](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport) to my app was easy enought, but that's when trouble started.

First, I had to search what strategy I needed, and all of them seems to require the server to maintain sessions/remember who is logged in, all the while using JWT internally. That seems contradictory, JWT is supposed to remove the need of maintaining session.

Finally, I found [this MS example](https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/AppModelv2-WebAPI-nodejs) which use the Bearer strategy without session.

After setting it up (changing the config file for the right tenant, client ID, changing the routes for a test app more representative of my API), I tried to use them. The protection work well since I am indeed "Unauthorized". But how do I get a valid token to send?

The [MSDN guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devquickstarts-webapi-nodejs) that use that quickstart don't mention it at all, just redirecting to the AAD library for Android or iOS, implicitely telling me to develop a test app in another language when I just want a crude tool to test if my test server work at all!

That is especially frustrating since I am pretty sure it is "just" a series of HTTP(S) request on the tenant, and the call to the api with the token attached, but I can't find anything to do just that.

**/!\**: I know asking for something as vague as "How can I do that" isn't a good question, and this question isn't one. What I am asking is why I couldn't find some tools like POSTMan that implement OAuth and allow to quickly test and debug a OAuth protected API. What are the reason that push MSDN to tell me to write a custom tool myself instead of providing a barebone one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code sample you mentioned in the post is using the Azure AD V2.0 endpoint. We can use **OAuth 2.0 code grant** and **client credentials** flows to acquire the token from this endpoint.

To compose the OAuth 2.0 request directly you can refer the links below:

[v2.0 Protocols - OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code)

[Azure Active Directory v2.0 and the OAuth 2.0 client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-client-creds)

In addition, **the access tokens issued by the v2.0 endpoint can be consumed only by Microsoft Services. Your apps shouldn't need to perform any validation or inspection of access tokens for any of the currently supported scenarios. You can treat access tokens as completely opaque. They are just strings that your app can pass to Microsoft in HTTP requests**(refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-tokens)).

If you want to protect the custom web API with Azure AD, you can use the Azure AD v1.0 endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

For getting a valid token to send to your API, you'll need to do an auth request to login.microsoftonline.com and get an access token (in the JWT format).  Then you can send this token to your api in the http body: "Bearer ey...".

If you want a full sample with a client app that hits that API sample you tried:

[Dashboard w/ all the samples for Azure AD Converged Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-appmodel-v2-overview)

[Simple Windows Desktop App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-devquickstarts-wpf)

[Angular SPA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-devquickstarts-angular-node)

[Node Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-devquickstarts-node-api)